# Conductance of disordered conductor

Tags: greens-functions, disorder, self-energy

I'm struggling with a rather advanced problem. Consider a conductor placed between two leads. The conductor is not completely clean but contains all kinds of impurities. The goal is to find the conductance of the conductor from a simulation.

By defining a grid in the conductor the self-energy can approximately be calculated and from that the Green's function. This Green's function can then be used to calculate the conductance. I don't know how to do the las step. This method is supposed to be used often in condensed matter physics.

Does someone have experience with this kind of problem. Do you know a good source that really offers elaborate explanations and derivations?

Appreciate any help.

Physics student

Comment: I know a little bit more. I think it is called the impurity averaged correlator: <Gretarded x Gadvanced>. Does someone know a good source to calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the conductance is to use the calculated self-energy and include it in the Hamiltonian. The resulting effective Hamiltonian can then be used to do a normal simulation for the conductance.